# Over the www, does the server see my mac address?

Tags: networking, ip, vpn, packet, mac-address

I'm just beginning to learn about ARP and networks.  Was wondering if in end to end communication say between facebook and my computer, do the 2 ends know each others mac addresses?

Or does only my router know my mac adress, and the directly next link from it know its, and so on so that facebook only knows (out of the devices in this particular communication) the mac adress of the final router to pass my request to it?

I watched a Stanford video that seemed explain my mac adress gets put into the ip packet that goes to my router which is then enclosed in a packed containing its mac adress which gets passed down the chain.  But I imagine I must be misunderstanding this otherwise a VPN wouldnt be able to fool the other end unless I simultaneously spoofed my mac address, right?

Thank you!

Comment: Why does a VPN need to "fool the other end"??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Was wondering if in end to end communication say between facebook and
>   my computer, do the 2 ends know each others mac addresses?

No, they don't know.

> Or does only my router know my mac address, and the directly next link
>   from it know its, and so on so that facebook only knows (out of the
>   devices in this particular communication) the mac adress of the final
>   router to pass my request to it?

Yes, check below for more details.

> Over the www, can the server see my MAC address?

Not directly, but, there can be a trail of search to get upto your MAC address. Actually, MAC address changes in every hop of the packet's journey. So, your MAC address can be stored in packets received by the first router/system to which your system/router passes packets.

Only those devices can see a MAC address which are on the same LAN network.

> I must be misunderstanding this otherwise a VPN wouldnt be able to
>   fool the other end unless I simultaneously spoofed my mac address,
>   right?

This is a very big story, but, in short, you could say that VPN's can fool in the cases when the MAC address has been spoofed or the proxy agent/server has been used for retrieving the same information. So, in that case, one can't get directly to the MAC address. But, remember, nothing is impossible, just hard.